# 12 volt kid car charging

Tags: 12v

Kid car use a 12 volt batterie, that need to be charge.

We need to Open the front car motor cover and unplug the connector for the batterie and plug the charger direct to battery for charging

I would like to to like a real car charging station

External or the car

With a light red when need charging and green when the charge is done install on the car

And a male female plug in for charging

What would be the circuit

I did one with a relay, my issue is when I plug charger, relay go ON light go ON but when I unplug the charger the 12 volt battery keep the relay ON

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a schematic of what you did? Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: don't you have a charger already?

Comment: There is a schematic editor built into site.  Edit your question.  Looks like a resistor, a capacitor and diode in parallel.

Comment: Hi thanks , the answer with the relay will works

Comment: To do this , you need to show your battery, charger  and get the same connector to charge in parallel

Answer (score 1):

Five or ten turns of one of the charger wires round a reed switch capsule will make a current relay that responds to the charging current, so when the charge is finished or when it is unplugged it will respond instantly.

use the switch part of that in series with your existing relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3wVWj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The light could be in parallel in the current relay ?

Comment: Where reed switch will be install ? In série in the plus charger side ?

Comment: the charger current flows through the wire coil around the reed switch,  the switch itself passes current to other relay.

Comment: Thanks very munch, any other device to replace Reed switch ?

Comment: Nothing less expensive or more readily available.  any place that sell alarm parts should have reed switches.